# When to detect application shutdown?

Tags: android

I have an app that automatically transmits location data to servers in the background (yes, this is necessary) but needs to do it while the activity is destroyed to save memory (i.e. `onDestroy()` won't work) but I want my app to terminate these operations when "swiped away" in the running applications view.

Is it even necessary to do this or will threads be interrupted automatically?

EDIT: I learned about services myself, but I am going to award the bounty to the person with the most comprehensive example of using them. (I don't need it myself but I think the current answers are not worthy of a bounty.)

Comment: You have to create your own aplicación file. And indicate that in your manifest. So with that, you can Override some methods, i think you need onDestroy()/ to detect that. Regards

Comment: @MaxPinto Yes, I already have a custom application. So is what you're saying is that `onDestroy()` works on applications?

Comment: @MaxPinto I don't see the callback [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) and its not highlighted in my editor when I create the mehtod.

Comment: Yes, i was wrong sorry. But look my answer:

Comment: _Is it even necessary to do this or will threads be interrupted automatically?_ It is not necessary. The `Activity` will only ever be "destroyed to save memory" when the whole process is terminated by the system for that purpose...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> yes, this is necessary) but needs to do it while the activity is destroyed to save memory

I got a feeling you are doing something wrong. Why is sending location to remote peer coupled with activity lifecycle? I do not see any sense of doing that. If you want to send location only when you are in foreground you can utilise [ActivityLifecycleCallbacks](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks.html) so you can be notified when you went into foreground or background and stop your **separate** sending worker when you go into background or resume when your activity become front-most one.

As for recent list related question, let me paste this comment by Dianne Hackborn:

> what specifically happens when you swipe away a recent task is it: (1)
>   kills any background or empty processes of the application (see
>   http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/processes-and-threads.html#Lifecycle
>   for what this means), and (2) uses the new
>   http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onTaskRemoved(android.content.Intent)
>   API to tell any services of the application about the task being
>   removed so it can do whatever it thinks is appropriate.

you can find this post here: https://plus.google.com/105051985738280261832/posts/GfwRYCC42uX (I failed to find the way to link directly to the comment on google plus thing).

Comment: Yes, looks like a background `Service` is the right solution given the requirements.

Comment: OK, I learned about how to use services. But if you could provide a comprehensive example on it, I can award you the reputation.

Answer (score 1):

Create a class extending the `Service` class. You need to register the class in your `manifest` (Tons of working examples on the internet). Then you have to decide how the Communication between your `Service` and your `Activity` should work. You canuser one of the following methods:

1. Using a `Messenger` ([Example](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Messenger))
2. Using `Intent`s and by registering a `BroadcastReceiver` ([Example](http://www.intertech.com/Blog/using-localbroadcastmanager-in-service-to-activity-communications/))
3. Using AIDL (You should better not try this one due to its high complexity)

I think you will have to look up the examples yourself. Philipp Heckel created some classes extending the original `Service` class and implementing the Service to Activity communication. [`ServiceManager.java` & `AbstractService.java`](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~binwiederhier/+junk/android-service-example/files/head:/src/com/philippheckel/service/) can be used to create such a service you need. Furthermore the implementation is quite simple. ([Full Example](http://blog.philippheckel.com/2012/06/10/android-example-communication-between-activity-and-service-using-messaging/))

Answer (score 0):

Create your own`Activity`, `BaseActivity` and extend to `Activity`, Override the `onDestroy()` method, and kn that method make your code.

So then your other activities extends your base `Activity`, and Override the `onDestroy()` method, and call `súper.onDestroy()` to apply the parent actions.

If i were you, i'd do it this way.
Could be other better way, of course, but is a solución-(solution).

Comment: This poses the same problem I was asking. [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy%28%29), it says "or because the system is destroying it to save space". So when the activity goes out of view, it'll be destroyed whether or not the application is closed. One method is to use `isFinishing()`, but does `finish()` get called when the application is swiped away?

Comment: well to add to your answer-(i didnt want to put it in your answer to so as to put words in your mouth) you can skip all the overrides by using activityalias and put the geo location updates in the oncreate and give it no target activity with that you can check isFinishing() there and decide whether to continue or exit is better than relying on onDestroy() but you should also put it in onDestroy() just so in case. Activityalias is a subset of an Activity.. hope its helpful and to your question @JamesLu yes

Comment: @JamesLu: Again, the system only destroys the `Activity` unilaterally when the whole process is killed. The "finishing" state of the `Activity` merely means that the `Activity` has been finished manually (by the user pressing back or otherwise programmatically by the developer).

Answer (score 0):

Why do not use an intentService to transmit the location data? It will continue working (=transmitting) if the app is killed.

If you only want to send the data when the app goes off then you can launch the intentService at onStop() method (as pointed on another answer extend Activity to avoid overriding all onStop one by one).

Comment: Good suggestion about using a `Service`. The rest of the answer is unnecessary, and doesn't make sense.