# Is there a way to execute a code block when android device is about to shutdown

Tags: android, shutdown

Is there a way for an app to detect android shutdown/restart and execute a code block?
I have a problem at hand that specifically requires to send email before device is shutting down and was wondering if you could do it.

Comment: You see this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31920603/when-to-detect-application-shutdown

Comment: @MagdalenaRowicka the mentioned answer only discusses application shutdown but the case here is device shutdown so I guess it doesn't comply with that.